# Not able to get the value of summernote in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, summernote

> I am setting the value of summernote code to hidden field but in code behind hidden field returns empty string

`Javascript code`

```
 $("#<%= txtQuestion.ClientID %>").on('summernote.blur', function () {
                    debugger;
                    let a = $('#<%= txtQuestion.ClientID %>').summernote('code');
                    document.getElementById("<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>").innerText = a;
                console.log(a);
                });
```

`Code Behind`

```
string a = HiddenField1.Value;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're setting `innerText`, you should set `value`.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp